# How to predict binary value in classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, predict

Currently, I should analize some data(about below table). I want to get some predicted value based on data. So, I search data analysis's algorithm(in the scikit-learn), but I can't get what I find the algorithm. Because I want to get predict value as binary(Such as 0 or 1),but Linear, SVN etc algorithms predict the value as a integer(like a average value). Below tables are more explained.

[ Trained - data ]

```
age | gender | education | result 
45  |   1    |     9     |   Y
23  |   2    |     12    |   Y
27  |   2    |     9     |   N
31  |   1    |     11    |   Y
45  |   1    |     9     |   N
```

[ Predicted - data ]

```
age | gender | education | result 
21  |   1    |     12    |   ?
32  |   2    |     11    |   ?
26  |   1    |     11    |   ?
54  |   1    |     9     |   ?
23  |   2    |     13    |   ?
```

I just want to get the predict value as Y or N. I searched scikit-learn(http://scikit-learn.org/stable/), but I don't know the best algorithm. 
Who know that? thanks!

Comment: As your target variable `result` predicts a binary value, it is a binary classification problem. You can search various classification algorithms present in `sklearn` and find one which suits the purpose.

Comment: Oh.. I see. Thank you.. have a good day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sklearn supports [all of these](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning) in terms of classification.

If the idea is to build an interpretable model, then the [LogisticRegression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression) might be the way to go.

It builds a model of the type: `logit(Result) = b0+b1*age+b2*gender+b3*education`. It estimates the `b` coefficients for you and you can then interpret it like: As age increases by 1, holding everything else fixed, then result will increase by `exp(b1)`. See more [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/odds_ratio.htm).

In addition there are a bunch of statistical tests available to test how robust it is. It's a pretty cool model and widely used in econometrics, but it assumes linearilities. For instance, your `result` variable (whatever it means) might increase more at old age than at an young age. So, you might want to aggregate your ages into groups. Furthermore, you may want to [one-hot encoding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) some of your factors, because of non-linearilities.

An easier to use model, which is also interpretable, is the [DecisionTree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html). See the link for examples of such trees.

If interpretabilitity is not an issue, a [SVM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) or something like [nearest neighbors](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html) or a [neural network](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html) might be the way to go. Usually, data scientists use [nested cross-validation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13185/nested-cross-validation-and-selecting-the-best-regression-model-is-this-the-ri/13232#13232) to try a bunch of models with a bunch of parameters. The outer cross-validation tests a bunch of different models with the inner cross-validation testing the hyperparameters.

Ah - forgot to mention. With regard to decision trees, you should take particularly care of fine-tuning the `max_depth` hyperparameter (but also fine-tune the others). You might also try some ensembles. Ensembles are when you create lots of models and then they all vote democratically on the prediction. They usually improve accuracy a lot. For decision trees, two very cool ensembles are [RandomForest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) and [Gradient Boosting Trees](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html).

Tell me if there is something else you want me to clarify. Anyhow in the future, please tell us 1. what you have tried so far, and 2. exactly what you want to do. Classification is a **huge** field in data science. This is the best I can do with the information you provided. :)